# How to turn off the dell alienware 15 keyboard light

Tags: keyboard, dell, xinput, alienware

How to turn off the dell alienware 15 keyboard light on ubuntu.

```
ake@alies-Alienware-15-R3:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Heng Yu Technology XEN108                 id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Heng Yu Technology XEN108                 id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: I don't feel like turning my lights off or changing colours or light show to music so haven't researched this. However ArchLinux has a link that might be helpful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Alienware_13#Keyboard_lights

Comment: google OpenRGB, I'm not sure if it is (Dell) related - but maybe. [ Works for my Asus laptop ]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/trackmastersteve/alienfx

This fixed light controls for me in Alienware 13 r3. Just follow the instructions one by one.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1207920)